# Not able to retrieve profile pic with fb login

Tags: android, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I followed the tutorial of facebook on their official page:

[Facebook Login tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/personalize)

However, after I finished this I do can login, but it doesn't retrieve my profile picture. Anyone else experienced this or has an idea what might cause this? I am getting no errors whatsoever..

Comment: try my  given answer and let me know if your problem is solved :)  happy coding and developing apps

Comment: @DeepakPanwar Thanks, I got back at you, cause some things are still unclear for me..

Comment: So what are the things that are not clear to you.?

Comment: See my comment to your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are clear upto getting facebook useUserId and FacebookToken.

Profile picture get can be done in two ways:

1: Facebook has provided you a view for profile picture `ie ProfilePictureView

in place of imageview in xml layout file take this view.

At the time of loadng image in this view simply do

```
ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.friendProfilePicture);
        profilePictureView.setCropped(true);
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(USER_ID);
```

2: Another Option is get profile picture with the help of facebook token

```
ImageView imgProfilePic12=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);

new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic12)
                .execute("https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=normal&method=GET&access_token="
                        + Faceboo_Access_Token);


/**
     * Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
     * */
    private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;

        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;

            try {

                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I see all answers there appear to be 3? What makes your option 2 for example the better one comparing to the first one and Riddhi Sah's one? I mean, what is the advantage of coding it apart if facebook already provides it? More transparancy in the coding?

Comment: Yes facebook has provided this new option of facebook query language, You can opt whatever you want. But when you think about customization of imageview in your code then you can opt for my option 2 and Riddhi Shah option 3.

Comment: So if I would use the LoginButton or ProfilePicture widget facebook sdk provides there is not much more I can do (f.e. to save this in a root database) with it? I should more use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started, so not the hard coded widgets of facebook itself?

Comment: Yes when you want customization in code,You should use your own controls(android widgets).

Answer (score 1):

have you successfully logged in Facebook ? 
if yes then

```
try {
                            JSONObject fbResObj = new JSONObject(fbUser
                                    .getInnerJSONObject().toString());
                            String id = fbResObj.getString("id");
                            url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + id
                                    + "/picture?style=small");
                            Log.v(TAG, url.toString());
                            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url
                                    .openConnection().getInputStream());


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

try this , where fbUser is the object of GraphUser which u get on executing GraphUserCallBack,

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void getUserDetail() {

        String fqlQuery = "SELECT name,uid,pic  FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())";
        Bundle _params = new Bundle();
        _params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
        Session _session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Request _request = new Request(_session, "/fql", _params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                if (graphObject != null) {
                    if (graphObject.getProperty("data") != null) {
                        try {
                            String _arry = graphObject.getProperty("data").toString();
                            JSONArray _jsonArray = new JSONArray(_arry);
                            if(_jsonArray.length()==1)
                            {
                                //here u will get your user's userId and Profile Picture and Name
                            String _uid = _jsonObject.getString("uid");
                            String _Name = _jsonObject.getString("name");
                            String _ImagePath = _jsonObject.getString("pic");
                            }

                                }


                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            if (ex != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(_request);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have Facebook id of user to get image use this link

https://graph.facebook.com/**FACEBOOK_USER_ID**/picture?type=large";

for small image use type = small