# Android & Facebook SDK : decoding pictures from /me/picture graph call

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

EDIT: Anwser at the end of this post.

I am trying to get a Facebook user's profile picture thanks to the inbuilt Facebook SDK's function **`Request()`**.

I am using a **`/me/picture`** call to get the profile picture and convert it into a **`Bitmap`**.

**The call is working fine but I don't know how to interpret and parse the result returned from Facebook**

Here is the **`JSON`** that I get:

{
"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT" : "����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000��\u0000\u0004*\u0000��\u0000C\u0000\u0006\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0005\u0004\u0006\u0006\u0005\u0006\u0007\u0007\u0006\b"
}

I think this should be representing the profile picture but I don't know what to do with this now.

If somebody could tell me either how to decode it, convert it to a Bitmap or what kind of data it is, I would be grateful.

**NOTES: I don't want to use any other function than Request(), like DecodeStream() or an AsyncTask**

---

Here is the answer:

When making a new `Request()` you need to add the "redirect" parameter to `false`:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putBoolean("redirect", false);
```

This will return the correct picture URL:

```
{
"data":{
      "is_silhouette":false,
      "url":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-xpa1\/v\/t1.0-1\/p100x100\/10312434_10152395442477210_2933994167675146084_n.jpg?oh=f3c8cb920c97fcfa4dc5e17462445cbf&oe=54404A3A&__gda__=1412730795_5f288e34e5f6e63cb1c3791dcb142880"
   }
}
```

Comment: Try This may be it help you :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034524/not-able-to-retrieve-profile-pic-with-fb-login/25035043#25035043

Comment: See my answer below. You just have to put your url in that code

Comment: Thanks sAyVII. Works fine here.

Comment: Thanks I was using string there instead of boolean wasted 3 hours.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
ImageView user_picture;
userpicture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.userpicture);
URL img_value = null;
img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large");
Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
userpicture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
```

Where ID is one your profile ID.

For Further details check this :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Comment: this answer got me going in the right direction, thanks!
Using the GraphApi callback - for the url, this is what worked for me: `String picUrlString = (String) response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("data").get("url");`.  From this post: https://dennisegert.wordpress.com/2015/08/16/android-facebook_non_json_result-when-trying-to-retrieve-the-profile-picture/